# iOS tab view page indicator

Tags: ios, tabs, scrollview, indicator

I am wondering whether there is a library that supports page indicators by tabs. So when users swipe a page, the tab indicator is changed also. On Android, we have a lib called  [ViewPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

We might do it manually, but it could save time if someone has done it already.

Thank you.